# Check if a Javascript function exist from Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am currently implementing JS Bridge in an Android WebView. I need to know if the webpage I open have a JavaScript function or not. If there is no function defined I need to handle it from native.

I know it is possible in JavaScript. But how do I do it from Kotlin/Java? Thanks.